# Skip Blank Values With PasteSpecial in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried various solutions that I've found online, but with no luck yet. Here is my VBA code to copy cells from about 30 sheets and paste them all onto one sheet. Each sheet has Formulas in 4 columns that show a value if there is a value in another sheet. Like this:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A2<>"", Sheet1!A2, "")
```

Then I run my macro on the page that I want it to output:

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        ws.Range("A2:D5406").Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), SkipBlanks:=True
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

The output results in a lot of blank cells after the ones with actual values in them.

I tried putting that "SkipBlanks" variant in there, but that wasn't the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered for me on excelforum.com, co I figured I'd post the solution here in case it helps anyone else.

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        ws.Range("A2:D5406").Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=False
    End If
Next ws

'Try inserting this line
'***********************************************************************

Worksheets("Summary").Select

'************************************************************************
'Find the last used row in column 1
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Insert a formula in column E to return the row number of any non blank row
Range("E1:E" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",ROW())"

'Copy Paste Values to remove the formula
Range("E1:E" & LR).Value = Range("E1:E" & LR).Value

'Sort your data
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1:E" & LR) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:E" & LR)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'Clear Column E
Range("E1:E" & LR).ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```